# Python keep socket connection alive

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, flask, uwsgi

I have a Python2.7 server with flask, flask_socketio, uwsgi

Here is a code sample:

```
from fit.app import app
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from fit.query import getESValue

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('get_client_info')
def handle_message(data):
    client = data["client"]
    p_id = data["p_id"]
    esvalues = getESValue(client, None, p_id)
    emit('client_results', {"client": client, "data": esvalues})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

**esvalues = getESValue(client, None, p_id)** is a high weight operation that can take up to 15 minutes.

But then it is successfully finished, I'm trying to send results to client side and receive following errors:

> Receive error
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 209, in _websocket_hand
>   ler
>       self.receive(pkt)
>     File "venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 53, in receive
>       self.send(packet.Packet(packet.PONG, pkt.data))
>     File "venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 67, in send
>       raise IOError('Socket is closed')
>   IOError: Socket is closed

and then this one:

> error: (9, 'Bad file descriptor')
>   Wed Jul 26 13:29:28 2017 Greenlet at 0x7f4ba547be10: select_greenlet_runner(9, )> failed with error

I think that I'm trying to use socket connection that has been closed. 
How can I keep it alive until 15 minutes task is finished ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue can be resolved by setting the timeout option when starting the server. It can be achieved by changing this line:

```
socketio.run(app)
```

To

```
socketio.run(app, ping_timeout=3600)
```

Change 3600 to match your reuquirements

Comment: could you please provide python version of it ?

Comment: i'm downvoting because the answer doesn't explain anything and actually fails to specifically do what OP asked

Comment: @ВласБоюс This might help